# ZF2 routing in links not working correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, config, standards

I'm working on a Zend Framework 2 application for work in which I can't seem to route correctly or know where to route it.

I have an Hostname => webapp.foo-bar.com. We decided to add a Subhost => /app/ to the end and the name of this app is called => app. I have a link on a page which it's route would be say => /graph/page-name. But when I hover over the link which looks like:

```
<a href="/graph/page-name">FooBar</a>
```

I'd get webapp.foo-bar.com/graph/page-name as opposed to webapp.foo-bar.com/app/graph/page-name.

My Application config is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'hostname',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'webapp.foo-bar.com/app',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
// Placeholder for console routes
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

I saw there is an option like:

```
<a href="<?=$this->url('application/default', array('controller' => 'graph', 'action' => 'page-name')?>">FooBar</a>
```

Would this need to be done on every link, or would we be able to do it in the config level?

Thanks!

---

Update:

I've managed to get the client to go down using the this->url() method and things are looking fine. Links are working even in the jQuery sections. I am having a small issue in relation to a link going to another controller not showing the action in the link.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('foo-bar', array('action' => 'bar-foo'))?>?year=2015"</a>
```

Brings back webapp.foo-bar.com/app/foo-bar?year=2015. I want it to return webapp.foo-bar.com/app/foo-bar/bar-foo?year=2015. Is this a configuration in the Controller of foo-bar or can it be done in this-url()?

Thanks a million for all the help given. Really appriciate it!

Comment: Who owns the `graph` controller - main host or subhost? Which exact thing do you want?

Comment: The graph controller belongs to the subhost. The main thing I want is to be able to configure higher up in the application to make href links like href="/graph/page-name" (which when clicked on gives me webapp.foo-bar.com/graph/page-name) to act like webapp.foo-bar.com/v2/app/graph/page-name. Hope I explained that a bit better as the $this->url() method isn't wanted unfortunately as most links are hard coded. Thanks a million for any help @jobaer

Answer (score 1):

If both apps share the same domain, then your configuration is invalid. My version of config file is below.

P.S. I created separate module Sample, so it would not interfere with Application config.

```
use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use \Sample\Controller\IndexController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;


return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'v2' => [
                'type' => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/v2/app',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => IndexController::class,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'child_routes' => [
                    'index' => [
                        'type' => Literal::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '/',
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => IndexController::class,
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'application' => [
                        'type' => Segment::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'route' => '[/:action]',
                            'defaults' => [
                                'controller' => IndexController::class,
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

This is how you create links to that application:

```
<?php echo $this->url("v2/application", ['action' => 'page-name']) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks akond for your answer. I'll give this a shot once I'm back in work. Would that have all links use the v2/app? Also should that change be made in all modules or could I change the application module to use the full change for links to work correctly with v2/app?

Comment: I forgot to add just one line. See the bottom of my post.

Comment: Ah cool thanks! Is that line needed to be able to create the link? I need the links to stay the way they are as there has already been many links added using the href="graph/page-name" format that I need to stay that way. And hopefully have the Config changed to add the v2/app change.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that without touching the links? Also thank you for your time :)

Comment: If `graph/page-name` moves to `v2/app/graph/page-name` then i am afraid the answer is no: you have to touch all those links.

Comment: *sigh* that's a shame. Needed to have it at the configuration level as it was opposed to change all the links.

Answer (score 1):

In ZF2 a route maps to a specific controller class and its action or method, so they can be of any modules. This route `graph/page-name` may map to `GraphController` and its method `pageNameAction()`, for example. But that can be any other controller and its actions. This depends on your needs.

Now lets come to the type of a route. There are some route plugins in ZF. These can be used to specify a route's type. For example, `Hostname` specifies domain name and subdomain like `subdomain.domain.tld`. But you are using `domain.tld/v2/app`. `Hostname` type does not allow `/` in the `'route' => 'subdomain.domain.tld'`. So this will not work, in this case.

You can get this type of endpoints (`domain.tld/v2/app`) without creating any subdomain that you said in your thread. That is why MVC pattern, Framework is more convenient. You can create a lot of endpoints for different purposes(`domain.tld/v1/abc` `domain.tld/v2/mno` `domain.tld/v3/xyz` etc) in your ZF application. They may be mapped to different controllers and actions from different modules.
So you do not need to be dependent on the subdomains as the way you asked.

You also said that you need `domain.tld/graph/page-name` which actually works as `domain.tld/v2/app/graph/page-name`. This means you want to hide this part `v2/app` from the url if I am not wrong. But this is still a challenge.

If you have it `graph/page-name` used under this `v2/app/graph/page-name` you may define your route as follows

```
// Top key of a route
'v2app' => [
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/v2/app',                   
        'defaults' => [
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
            'controller'    => 'Index',
            'action'        => 'index',
        ],
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => [
        'default' => [
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],                              
        'graph' => [
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '[/:controller/:action]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Graph',
                    'action' => 'pageName',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

You can add this to any route section of any `module.config.php` by correcting the module name, controller name etc. But **keep it mind that same configuration for multiple routes would make you unhappy**.

Now to output those routes use the following snippet of code

```
echo $this->url('v2app/graph', [], [], true);
echo $this->url(null, ['controller' => 'graph', 'action' => 'page-name']);

// outputs
// /v2/app/graph/page-name
```

while `v2app` is your top route key and `graph` is the child route of it.

Now you have said about how you should implement links. If you want to show them as menu, you do not have to code like that you said. You can [follow this to implement links as menu](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.navigation.quick-start.html). But keep it mind providing value (the top key of a route) for the route key while building an array for the navigation.
The following example from above for this route `graph/page-name`

```
[
    'label' => 'Graph',
    // route name not route pattern
    'route' => 'graph', // not /graph/page-name
],
```

Otherwise if you want to show a link in the body of a page you then use `$this->url()` helper as used above.

Please refer to this [DOC](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#http-routing-examples) for `Hostname` type.

If we can not help you here please [ask this here](https://discourse.zendframework.com/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay! That was a fierce informative answer. Going to try this and also go to the zend forum to see if anything else can be done. The other solution is a Virtual Host but I want to try and get best standards in the app as best I can first.

Comment: You may implement API centric architecture. Pull data from this url `domain.tld/v2/app/graph/page-name` so this would be your api endpoint and then show on this url `domain.tld/graph/page-name`. Otherwise, I am still hunting.

Comment: Wow thanks for still looking into it. Trying convince the client to allow me to just refactor it. Would the API be needed to be created for this? It already calls a AJAX call which pulls the info. Looking out myself for something!

Comment: Well, I have got some idea from your last reply. So I think you do not need to create that API. You may do this. For example, you have two modules in you app - one is for the API and the other is for client/user/you. So pull data from `v2/app/graph/page-name` using ajax and show them on the `graph/page-name` on the same domain.tld. So those routes would be for those modules respectively.

Comment: The page still needs to take the view of page-name and render it. Not sure about the API route as the client doesn't want to refactor the code, not sure about creating new code if you get me. Really thought that the configuration the route of the application would solve it oO Also thanks so much for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a cutomized [ViewModel](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html) that will contain own `url` implementation

```
/**
 * @param  \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e The MvcEvent instance
 * @return void
 */
public function setLayout($e)
{
    // Should return your customization
    $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
```

In that case all your `$this->url()` will do directly the same trick as:

```
$this->url('application/default', array('controller' => 'graph', 'action' => 'page-name')
```

---

As a partial example to customize render:

```
$customStrategy = $app->getServiceManager()->get('{Your class name}'); 
$view->getEventManager()->attach($customStrategy, 1); // 1 - means priority
```

Inside your class

```
preg_replace_callback('/<a href=\\"([^\\"]*)\\">(.*)<\\/a>/iU', function ($matches) {
    // do whatever you need for each URL
}, $content);
```

Or it can be used DOM object (but it's relying on your code validity):

```
$xpath = new \DOMXPath((new \DOMDocument)->loadHTML($content));
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[href]') as $link) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that and it worked but the question was can I keep away from using $this->url('application/default', array('controller' => 'graph', 'action' => 'page-name') as the client does not want to refactor their code. Seems we will have to refactor anyway as there is no other way.

Comment: If you are not going to change templates `<a href="/graph/page-name">FooBar</a>` to `<a href="<?= $this->url('/graph/page-name') ?>">FooBar</a>`. Then it can be overwritten `render` function that will catch all URLs by regexp and change them.

Comment: Oh, this isn't something I heard that would be amazing! How would this work? How much refactoring would be needed to have every link in the app (there is a lot :/) to stay the way it is but go as /app/graph/page-name. /v2/ is out of the question now. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around for this purpose. You may try this one. To do that you need to create a custom route plugin and then set that to route pointing to the `Graph` controller and its target method `pageNameAction()`, in this case. Please follow the steps below.

Here `graph/page-name` would work as `v2/app/graph/page-name` meaning the following link would work as you expect.

```
<a href="/graph/page-name">FooBar</a>
```

Please take the custom route plugin from [here](https://gist.github.com/unclexo/2fb8e9f11ef3fb4b1ac25f8a80ad8bcd). Put it under this `src/YourModuleName/Route` directory using the namespace `YourModuleName\Route`.

Notice you need to replace `'template_prefix'  => 'yourmodulename',` with your own module name with all small letters. View templates will be searched for by matching this patten `yourmodulename/controller/action-name` behind the scene.

```
'v2app' => [
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '[/v2/app]',             
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => 'YourModuleName\Controller\Index',
            'action' => 'index',
        ],
    ],
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => [                         
        'graph' => [

            // We call the custom route plugin thus  
            'type' => 'YourModuleName\Route\AppRoute',
            'options' => [
                'dir_name'         => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                'template_prefix'  => 'yourmodulename',
                'filename_pattern' => '/[a-z0-9_\-]+/',                     
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'YourModuleName\Controller\Graph',
                    'action' => 'pageName',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Now format the `pageNameAction()` as the following

```
public function pageNameAction()
{
    // Get path to view template from route params
    $pageTemplate = $this->params()->fromRoute('page', null);

    // If path is not valid
    if($pageTemplate == null) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404); 
        return;
    }       

    $viewModel = new ViewModel();

    // Here we set template to be rendered for `v2/app/graph/page-name`
    $viewModel->setTemplate($pageTemplate);

    return $viewModel;
}
```

If you need to output link in the view script use this way

```
echo $this->serverUrl('/graph/page-name');
```

Hope this would help you!